# fragment instance saving issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently working in an Application in which I have **1 activity** which contain frame and I am toggling 2 fragment in that from 2 bottom navigation button.
In **Fragment A** I am just displaying some content a and in **Fragment B** I am getting data from an API. As Many Time I am clicking on The Button B my Api get hit and data reloaded. I want to save the **fragment B** so that I can reuse that fragment again and again. I don't really know how to do that.

Once I think of storing it on backstack but once when I pop the backstack I had to again load the Api data.

Comment: Can you please add code of Fragment B?

Comment: use boolean variable to check if first time then load data from service other vise show loaded data.

Comment: I just want to save fragment B instance after it get loaded for the first time

Comment: @PriteshVadhiya my data get removed when i go to some other activity from that fragment

Comment: so you have to store in sqlite database and get it from if it's not first time

Comment: there is a way of saving fragment instance but I don't really know about that. And storing data in database i don't think so it is necessary @PriteshVadhiya

Comment: Either save it in preferences or sqlite DB or a static class to hold the values.

Comment: can i store whole framgment. like it store in backstack and use again and again?

Comment: You just use the same instance and reuse it.

Comment: but how can you explain little bit?

Answer (score 0):

You can just take a global ArrayList in MainActivity like :

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

In Fragment B you can just add all data in that global arraylist like :

```
arrayList.addAll(your-webservice-data);
```

If you will use same instance of fragment then you can just get data from global arraylist . Global ArrayList will not removed with changing the fragments.